# Making caption bold for only one table

Tags: tables, captions, bold

I am having trouble making only one caption bold without the rest of the captions within my document not bold. In this example below, I wish to have only the Table's caption bold without affecting the figure's caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable, stackengine}
\usepackage{array}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\textbf{Prisoner's Dilemma}}
\centering

    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc|}\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Soda Inc.} \\\cline{3-4}
& & High Price & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Low Price} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\Longstack{Cola Kings}}} & High Price & $50,50$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$10,60$}\\\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& Low Price & $60,10$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\underline{$30$},\underline{$30$}}\\\hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
This is a figure.
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you load the `caption` package and issue the instruction

```
\captionsetup{font=bf}
```

immediately after `\begin{table}` (and before `\caption{...}`). This setup will affect only the table caption, but not the later figure caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% deleted all packages not needed for the present example...
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\caption{Prisoner's Dilemma}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc|}\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Soda Inc.} \\
\cline{3-4}
& & High Price & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Low Price} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\Longstack{Cola Kings}}} & High Price & $50,50$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$10,60$}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& Low Price & $60,10$ &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\underline{$30$},\underline{$30$}}\\
\hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This is a figure. The caption isn't in bold\dots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```